# How to use articles with multiple nouns

Tags: english-to-german, grammatical-number

For example:

**Case 1**:

treat "a dog" and "a cat" as two single object

> Der Hund und die Katze sind nicht zu Hause.

or
Treat "a dog und a cat" as a combined plural object

> Die Hund und Katze sind nicht zu Hause

more example:

> Ein Handy mit der Hülle und der Folie

or

> Ein Handy mit den Hülle und Folie

Which one is right?

Comment: I removed the question about Du vs. Sie - it’s interesting, but too different from the article question that forms the main part. I encourage you to post a new question about the addressing groups of “Sie and du”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are multiple questions about the handling of **articles**. Not demonstrative pronouns, though you may see articles as a *pointing finger, light version*.

> *Der Hund und die Katze* sind nicht zu Hause.
>
> *Ein Hund und eine Katze* sind nicht zu Hause.
>
> *Hund und Katze* sind nicht zu Hause.

The items in the list have to agree in their use of articles. Be careful, *ein* may be understood as a number. Number words mix with both definite and indefinite articles.

> Zu Hause sind ein Hund und zwei Katzen.
>
> Zu Hause sind der Hund und zwei Katzen.
>
> Zu Hause sind ein Hund und die zwei Katzen.
>
> Zu Hause sind der eine Hund und die zwei Katzen.

Lists make a sentence item plural, regardless of the numbers of the individual list items.

> *Kein Hund und eine Katze* sind zu Hause.
>
> *Weder Hund noch Katze* sind zu Hause.

Same as in English: *Neither dog nor cat are at home.*

---

> Ein Handy mit **der** Hülle und (mit) **der** Folie.
>
> Ein Handy mit **den** Hülle**n** und (mit) **der** Folie.

The preposition *mit* takes the dative case. If you have a list of prepositional objects, an identical preposition for the later items may be ommitted. Each article has to agree with the individual number of the list item it belongs to.

---

*Now when a friend with a Professor stand in front from me, how should I express "you"? Use "ihr" oder “Sie”*

I seriouly doubt you can address both your friend and your professor with the same sentence. What **identical thing** you had to say to both of them? Most German speakers would not use any personal pronoun at all when addressing mixed groups.

> Vorsicht, Stufe!

*Mind the steps!*

Comment: *What identical thing you had to say to both of them?* Do you say "folgen Sie mir" or "folgt mir"? "Bitte folgen" would be impolite

Comment: I would address the Professor with *Sie* first then, and address the friends in another sentence *Ihr auch!*

Comment: If we have two nouns of the same gender connected with *und/or*, Which is better, to repeat the article before each noun or just using it one time before the first noun. E.g., *das Haus und das Auto* or *das Haus und Auto*?

Comment: If you want to list a number of items, you have to repeat the article in any case. Saying *das Haus und Auto* means *Haus* and *Auto* are one single entity with a two-part description/name. *Der Freund und Helfer ist da.* ← It's one single policeman.

Answer (score 4):

In a list connected with *und* we can [leave out the leading article](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html). This comes in handy when there are different genders:

> Hund und Katze sind nicht zu Hause.
>   Ein Handy mit Hülle und Folie.
>   Vater, Mutter und Kind sind eine Familie.

Comment: Won't that affect the meaning? *Sie reiste mit Zelt und Rucksack durch Malawi.* If we refer to a specific tent or backbag already mentioned (maybe with special features), can we simply omit the definite article without changing the meaning?

Comment: @User: of course. If we want to specify an item we do put an article .This special case does not apply to the examples of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Correct is:

> Der Hund und die Katze sind nicht zu Hause.

because each noun gets its own article, and the article depends on the number of the noun it precedes. An article is not shared by more than one noun.

Nonetheless, "der Hund und die Katze" is only one object. If it were two objects, the verb would be the third part of the sentence, which would violate the verb-second rule.

Case 3 is a very different case and should be a separate question. If you address a group of people with "Ihr", this is like addressing each person with "Du", so using "Sie" is the safer option, although this may feel too formal when a friend is among the group. You can only avoid this dilemma by not addressing the group as a whole.

Comment: Mostly agree, but "If it were two objects, the verb would be the third part of the sentence, which would violate the verb-second rule" is not a useful way to look at it. The pre-field can contain a wide array of structural units with different levels of complexity. It is perfectly fine to have conjoining noun phrases like _Der Hund und die Katze_ occupy the pre-field. The cat and the dog need not be treated as "one object" (which they aren't, as evidenced by the plural _sind_) - the verb-second structure of the sentence is not affected by that whatsoever.